# How to remove the first * of my output in a C program?

Tags: c, prime-factoring

i'm trying to write a program that print the prime factors of a given number, but i need to print them separeted by `*`, for example: for the input 100 the output will be: 2*2*5*5, any suggestions? i did this so far:

```
# include <stdio.h> 
# include <math.h> 

void decomposicao(int n) 
{ 
    printf("%d = ", n);

    while (n%2 == 0) 
    { 
        n = n/2;
        printf("* %d ", 2); 
    } 

    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2) 
    { 
        while (n%i == 0) 
        { 
            n = n/i; 
            printf("* %d ", i);     
        } 
    } 

    if (n > 2) 
        printf ("* %d ", n); 

} 
int main() 
{ 
    int n;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    if (n<=0||n==1)     
    {   
        printf("Error", n);
    }
    else
    {
        decomposicao(n);
    }   

    return 0; 
}
```

For this code the output is :

`100 = *2*2*5*5`

Comment: Depending on what you're feeding the output into, you could just print a "1" first, so the output would be `1*2*2*5*5`. (But I suppose that's cheating.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean variable that tells you whether you're printing the first factor or not.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

void decomposicao(int n) 
{ 
    bool first = true;
    printf("%d = ", n);

    while (n%2 == 0) 
    { 
        n = n/2;
        if (!first)
            printf("* ");

        printf("%d ", 2); 
        first = false;
    } 

    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2) 
    { 
        while (n%i == 0) 
        { 
            n = n/i; 
            if (!first)
                printf("* ");

            printf("%d ", i);
            first = false;  
        } 
    } 

    if (n > 2) {
        if (!first)
            printf("* ");

        printf ("%d ", n); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that in C you would need to include stdbool.h in order to use booleans, and compile with a C99-compliant compiler.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can change how * are being printed. Instead of at the begging of your string, just put it at the end.

Now, instead of written your results directly to the output stream, you can write to an internal buffer, and when you are finished, just ignore the last two char in it.

```
void decomposicao(int n) 
{ 
    const size_t len = 512;
    char buffer[len];
    size_t written = 0;

    written = snprintf(buffer, len, "%d = ", n);

    while (n%2 == 0) 
    { 
        n = n/2;
        written += snprintf(buffer + written, len - written, "%d * ", 2); 
    } 

    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2) 
    { 
        while (n%i == 0) 
        { 
            n = n/i; 
            written += snprintf(buffer + written, len - written, "%d * ", i);     
        } 
    } 

    if (n > 2) 
        written += snprintf(buffer + written, len - written, "%d * ", n); 

    buffer[len - 1] = '\0';
    buffer[written - 2] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

}
```